# Headless UWP Bluetooth pairing without user pin input

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, headless, windows-10-iot-core

I am currently building a headless UWP app running on Windows 10 IoT Core.  I need to be able to connect mobile devices to the kiosk via Bluetooth (RFCOMM) to harvest data.  I need to be able to initiate the pairing from the mobile devices.

I have experimented with all of the [UWP Bluetooth sample apps](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) but have mostly been experimenting with the *[Device Enumeration and Pairing C# sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing)* - specifically *Scenario 9 - Custom Device Pairing*.  I can successfully pair to a headed UWP app using pins but I have not been able to successfully pair to my headless UWP app - I either get a "failed" result or "authentication timeout" result when I try to initiate pairing.

How does one pair to a headless UWP app without the UI to retrieve a pin?  I could live with the UWP app having a hardcoded pin instead of a random pin for each pairing attempt but I'm not sure if the is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You might try with following code. When there are incoming pairing requests, the handlerUpdater will be invoked.

```
            handlerUpdated = new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformationUpdate>(async (watcher, deviceInfoUpdate) =>
            {
                // Since we have the collection databound to a UI element, we need to update the collection on the UI thread.
                await MainPage.Current.UIThreadDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, async () =>
                {
                    // Find the corresponding updated DeviceInformation in the collection and pass the update object
                    // to the Update method of the existing DeviceInformation. This automatically updates the object
                    // for us.
                    foreach (BluetoothDeviceInformationDisplay deviceInfoDisp in bluetoothDeviceObservableCollection)
                    {
                        if (deviceInfoDisp.Id == deviceInfoUpdate.Id)
                        {
                            if (deviceInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Pairing.CanPair)
                            {
                                await deviceInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly);
                            }

                            deviceInfoDisp.Update(deviceInfoUpdate);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            deviceWatcher.Updated += handlerUpdated;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've updated the DeviceWatcherHelper in the [Device Enumeration and Pairing C# sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) to include your suggested code.  Unfortunately I am still receiving an "authentication timeout" error.  Do you have any other suggestions?  I think it would be quite helpful to the Windows 10 IoT Core community to have a working headless UWP sample app which demonstrates pairing without a pin. I'd be more than happy to submit one but I need further guidance.